# New paypal ios sdk in not working in device

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I am developing one application.In that i am using New Latest pay pal API. Whenever i tried to that one,i got one alert like"**There was a problem with communicating with server**". And i didn't mention any customer id.Is it creating this problem? If not then how to connect pay pal server.My xcode version is 4.5,Base SDK is ios 6,target deployment is 5.0 and device OS version is ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention client ID and write below code:

```
[PayPalPaymentViewController prepareForPaymentUsingClientId:kPayPalClientId];
```

Comment: It's not working.Again iam getting that error.Actually iam from India.Is it any problem.In some postsi read this one is working in US only.

Answer (score 0):

The merchant account must be a US account. I don't know if sandbox will work for non-US merchant accounts or not.

For sandbox, you must also set `[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];` and `#define kPayPalClientId <YOUR CLIENT ID>` with the client ID that you get for sandbox from https://developer.paypal.com

Note also that the only tested configuration is for USD, thought that will change soon.